# Dropdown content visible with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I've created horrible-looking demonstration of my current issue. The Question is, how can I have overflow-y as scroll, and overflow-x visible, while expandable content remains visible for all it's size (without been cut by end of div)?

In this example, expandable content shows in its full size without overflow, but with overflow, it is just cut with border. Tried the workaround with wrapper, but actually it's not working at all :(

```css
body {
background-color: cyan;
}

.leftnav {
width: 8em;
height: 5em;
padding-right: 7em;
background-color: green;
color: white;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: visible;
direction: rtl;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5em;
  top: -1em;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p></p>


<div class="leftnav">

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: can you place it as a code snippet?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it ;)

Comment: You want "<p>Hello World!</p>" to be seen full-sized not contained within the parent, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, with playing around and a bit of googling, this is not possible without JavaScript. You can get it outside, however, the element loses its actual position if you scroll. It is quite an interesting problem, more on it you can find [here and problems solution](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/).

```js
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('.dropdown').on('mouseover', function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this),
        $submenuWrapper = $('> .dropdown-content', $menuItem);
    
    // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
    var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();
    
    // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $submenuWrapper.css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0.75)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: cyan;
position: relative;
}

.wrapper {position: relative;}

.leftnav {
width: 8em;
height: 5em;
padding-right: 7em;
background-color: green;
color: white;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: visible;
direction: rtl;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p></p>

<div class="wrapper">


<div class="leftnav">

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
```